# How old is our Sun in Galactic years?

Tags: the-sun, orbit

A year is measured as the amount of time it takes Earth to orbit the Sun once, a Galactic year is the time it takes our sun to make one full orbit of the center of the Galaxy.

In Galactic years, how old is our Sun?

Answer (score 15):

According to the blog [How old is the Sun in Galactic years?](http://scienceblogs.com/startswithabang/2008/02/27/how-old-is-the-sun-in-galactic-years/) (Siegel, 2008), a Galactic year is about 223 million Earth years.

The age of the Sun, according to the Stanford Solar Centre's page [How old is the Sun?](http://solar-center.stanford.edu/FAQ/Qage.html) is approximately 4.57 billion years.

This would put the sun at **approximately 20.5 galactic years old**.

Comment: Almost old enough to buy a galactic beer!

Comment: In some places, it already could.

Comment: @astromax Mmm...galactic beer. - Homer Simpson

Answer (score 6):

The Galactic rotation period at the Sun's Galactocentric radius is about 230 million years (with a five percent uncertainty) and the Sun, as stated in user8's answer is 4.57 billion years old - giving $\sim 20\pm 1$ orbits.

However, the idea of **a** Galactic year is misleading.  For instance, the Milky Way rotation curve is quite flat between 1 and 10 kpc from the centre (see picture), so the "year" also varies by a factor of 10 over this range, with the year being much shorter in the inner part of the Galaxy.

Therefore to know how many rotation periods the Sun has executed requires us to know at what Galactocentric radius it has spent its life. It is an *ongoing debate* as to whether the Sun has migrated to its position from outside or inside its current radius, or whether it has been where it is all along. As a result, how many "Galactic years" our Sun has experienced is still quite uncertain.

eg. see 
http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2015MNRAS.446..823M
http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2002MNRAS.336..785S
http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2013A%26A...558A...9M

[image: Milky Way rotation curve]

Answer (score 1):

Our sun takes about 225-250 million years to complete one galactic year (also called a cosmic year),so from the age of the sun it has completed approximately **19 galactic years**.

Comment: This answer adds nothing not already covered by the other answers.